# How to center middle element in a flutter row of 3 elements

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, row

**How to center middle element in a row of 3 elements** (where every element has different length), I want side elements to be maximally on the left/right side and middle element to be exactly on middle?

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text(
        'el',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Color(0xFFD50000),
        ),
      ),
    )),
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text('elem',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16,
          )),
    )),
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text('longest elem',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Color(0xFFD50000),
          )),
    )),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you are using `Expanded` everyone is getting flex:1. Now you can use `align` from Container and then `textAlign` to make it center(just one of them is needed).

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'elem',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center, //may work without it
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Children in your row are properly centered because your expanded takes as much space as possible for every widget on the row's main axis (horizontally). The proportion is decided by the [`Expanded.flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) property which defaults to 1 and thus in your case gives every child same amount of space.

Your Text widget isn't aligning the text in the center. To fix this, provide argument `TextAlign.center` to the parameter `textAlign` in your `Text` widgets.

Refer Flutter's API Documentation for [`Text.textAlign`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/textAlign.html), and [`Text` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text(
        'el',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center, // here
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Color(0xFFD50000),
        ),
      ),
    )),
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text('elem',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center, // here
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16,
          )),
    )),
    Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: Text('longest elem',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center, // and here
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Color(0xFFD50000),
          )),
    )),
  ],
);
```

Resultant UI for the above code:
[image: Result Flutter UI]

I recommend reading [this article on flutter. It explains a lot about constraints and alignment.](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: const Text(
                            'el',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Color(0xFFD50000),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.lightGreen,
                          child: const Text('elem',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center, //here
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 16,
                              )),
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text('longest elem',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.end, //here
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Color(0xFFD50000),
                              )),
                        )),
                  ],
                )
```

Is this what you need?
[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5AMJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).